# What's the point of encryption if there exists decryption?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

Let's say in database user password is encrypting in MD5 and it's no more readable by human, but i can copy MD5 hash and go to any website which provide MD5 decryption and get actually password. So am I missing something?

Comment: You don't *encrypt* passwords, you *hash* them.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using MD5 for hashing passwords anyway.

Comment: You need to read up on password hashing and related best practices...

Comment: When why need hashing any of data if it's easily recoverable ?

Comment: Because it's not easily recoverable *if you use a proper (cryptographic) hash*.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a one-way operation (hashing), it is not possible to decrypt it. But you can hash a lot of passwords and check whether the hashes are the same (brute-forcing). When you find a match, you can not know if that was the original password though, because many other passwords result in the same hash (collisions).

Mitigating brute-forcing and other cracking techniques is the goal of password-hash functions like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2. Absolutely use them instead of MD5 and you will see, that there exists no websites offering "decryption".